# SmartGWT Dynamic Form edit record with boolean values

Tags: checkbox, edit, smartgwt, mode

I've got following problem using SmartGWT 2.4:

- we are having a DynamicForm showing several static text fields (so the form is in readonly mode). The form uses a datasource in the background and our own **FormItemFactory** to create proper form items based on our meta data. Some of the form items contain boolean values displayed as strings: like *'isHidden': false* or *'canShow': true*.
- by user action (button click) we need to switch the form to edit mode.

We do it in following way:

- we first gather the form values as `rec = form.getValuesAsRecord()` getting a Record object
- then we create a new dynamic form and set into it the same datasource as original has
- then we call the `newForm.editRecord(rec)` method of newly created dynamic form

This way the form static values are shown as editable input fields. **However the problem is with those boolean values. They are correctly transformed into check boxes but all of them are checked by default.**

I think that the string values 'false' or 'true' are not parsed into boolean values and set as value for respective check box item.

Can I somehow influence this process? I tried to provide an anonymous implementation of **FormItemValueParser** to **CheckboxItem** but it turns out to be use only by free text form items.

I'll be really thankful for any given hint.

Comment: Can you post your code or a sample stand-alone code here?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the value explicitly to the formItem with record.getAttributeAsBoolean("formItemName")

```
BooleanItem boolItem = new BooleanItem("boolname");
DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();
form.setItems(boolItem);

//Get record
Record rec = form.getValuesAsRecord();
boolItem.setValue("boolname",rec.getAttributeAsBoolean("boolname"));
```

Comment: Thx for reply. The problem however is that those boolean form items are created as general FormItem objects. So calling rec.getAttributeAsBoolean() throws exception.

Comment: then try Boolean.valueOf(rec.getAttributeAsString("boolname"))